# Loop of refs for input default value

Tags: reactjs

I wan't to add a default value to dynamically added inputs. So i want to render refs by loop. I tried something like this

```
this.state.foods.forEach(el=> this[el.id] =  React.createRef() )
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea to render refs dynamically? I run this loop inside of a constructor.

Comment: You can't represent dynamically added inputs in state instead, with e.g. an array of all the input values, and you just add another empty string to it when you add an input?

Comment: Please post all of your code. If you have to change the state of an array `foods` you have to make a copy and completely replace it, you can't modify the array in state.

Comment: Why don't you just create an array and add data inside it and update it in the state object? while in render you can use map and iterate through each value in state and render inputs dynamically

Comment: This is full code http://pasted.co/b845799d basically i wan't to add edit functionality into my component, if u click a edit button it shows an input with default value of food name, and i wan't to change this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing refs for a dynamic amount of inputs you can store each food as a string in an array and update a string when its corresponding input change. This way you just have to add an empty string to the array to add a new food.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    foods: ["fish", "beef", "pasta"]
  };

  onChange = (index, food) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const foods = [...prevState.foods];
      foods[index] = food;
      return { foods };
    });
  };

  addFood = () => {
    this.setState(({ foods }) => ({ foods: [...foods, ""] }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.foods.map((food, index) => (
          <div>
            <input
              key={index}
              value={food}
              onChange={event => this.onChange(index, event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.addFood}>Add food</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: But what if my foods is array of objects wchich each object is stored like that {food: 'pasta', calories: 23, id: '1'} ?

Comment: @KacperŁukasik That will work great as well. Then you just have to add a new object instead of an empty string in `addFood`, and change the rendering/onChange logic a bit.

Comment: It's working! Thank you! But can u explain me what is that "prevState => "?